# What should you use to design a menu?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF development with C#, and I'm trying to develop an application using Kinect, but I don't what I should use for new screens? I see there are Pages, UserControls and Windows.

What I want to achieve is have the MainWindow.xaml as main menu which will have a number of buttons. Once a button is pressed, it brings in a new screen with more options, which could then bring in another screen with more buttons etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general:
Windows are for your top level windows/screens.
Pages are for browser applications, and user controls are for smaller reusable collections of controls.

So MainWindow is definitely a window, as would be any popup screens or dialogs. Subscreens that appear within your main screens would be user controls.